# Why are my frontend theme styles bleeding into the backend?

Tags: wp-admin, css, front-end

I'm developing a custom theme. For some reason, some of the styles I define globally in the front-end (like certain styles for headings and such) are affecting the back-end.

I am using the [WP-LESS plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-less/) and enqueueing the main stylesheet in the theme's functions.PHP:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'mainLESS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/less/index.less');
```

Is this normal behaviour?

How should I prefix styles to keep them from applying to the backend? I don't seem to be seeing any obvious body classes I could take advantage of.

Comment: How did you add the styles to your theme? Like the code please :)

Comment: ^- what he said. You could make use of [`is_admin()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) to not enqueue the style or (`body:not(.wp-admin)` which seems like an overkill)

Comment: @kraftner, kero - I am using [WP-Less](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-less/) and doing `wp_enqueue_style( 'mainLESS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/less/index.less');` in the theme's functions.php. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: I'm still not seeing your actual code as an edit to the question ;)

Comment: @kraftner done!

Comment: @Pekka웃 This is the way to do it, [look how twentysixteen is enqueing styles](https://github.com/WordPress/twentysixteen/blob/master/functions.php#L245). Most are always enqueued and some only for specific pages. I guess the question is what CSS are you writing that changes the backend as well? Btw, if you have specific styles for the wp-admin, you'd usually use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: What hook are you in when you enqueue them? Probably `init` or so, but not `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: @kero none at all - that was my mistake. Thanks to you, too!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're supposed to enqueue on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` event. Placing the function in `functions.php` and immediately running it, will make it run on all pages, including the admin area

Here's an example from the devhub:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

This hook/action/event fires on the frontend. If you would like to add a style or script to the backend, use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` event instead